# Using wso2 identity server and office 365 via outlook

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are trying to configuration wso2 Identity Server 5.0.0 to federate our Office 365 environment using SAML.

It works fine for the Office 365 web components, yet appears to break Outlook clients.

Specifically, we saw Outlooks Auto Discover break with this error:
X-AutoDiscovery-Error: LiveIdBasicAuth:FederatedStsUrlNotEncrypted:[X-forwarded-for:13.67.59.89][HRD-Business-0ms-249ms-ppserver=PPV: 30 H: CH1IDOALGN161 V: 0][GetDomainInAD-1ms]Federated STS endpoint '**http://dummystsurl.microsoftonline.com/dummyurl**' is not secured using HTTPS. Aborting request for user ""[tarpit suggested][UserType:ManagedBusiness];

Is there a value we should be coding for Office 365’s parameter ‘ActiveLogOnUri’?

Is there a better way to accomplish this than SAML?

Thanks,
…pat

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed as having the same issue with another SAML provider.

Comment: Our problem turned out to be a permission issue in IS, where we had not allowed STS to "Everyone".

Comment: Ah thank you, just got to the bottom of ours and our SAML provider doesn't support ActiveLogOnUri only passive :(

Comment: now the current WSO2 IS 5.2.0 supports the active logon uri /services/mex-ut